# How to convert Svmlight data to a database

Tags: database, sparse-matrix, libsvm, svmlight, sparse-file

I am using data in Svmlight format (you may know it as libsvm)

[this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61328/libsvm-data-format) is the format

I tried to create a SQL database to store it, the issue is that the format is sparse, and in a regular database it will be very consuming to store the data, and if i store it in a sparse format (string for every row) i can't query stuff by their column wise content (e.g -> i need to query for all the rows that contain value for feature #)

I am looking for a straight forward way to convert it to a database that will make filtering and querying faster and more simple.

Can anyone point me to a suiting database solution and if possible an already made utility that makes to conversion?

Thanks!